# How to access protected properties from an Obj C Library in Swift?

Tags: swift, properties, protected

I don't know how to access the @protected properties from a Objective-C lib in swift. For example

Obj-C Library Code:

```
@interface MyLibVC : UIViewController { 
   @protected
   UIButton *myButton;
   CustomClass *myClass;
}
```

How do I access this code in my Swift file if I import myLibVC? All other properties are available except the protected ones.

Comment: *It is protected variable not property

Answer (score 0):

self.valueForKey("myButton") is the only way I could access the variable.